# Issue with chart.js skipping between charts modified with button click

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Im having an issue updating charts with Chart.js.
Using hardcoded data within the javascript I'm passing new data into the chart function on a button click event, however once the chart has been updated once it seems to skip between the 2 instances when hovering over the charts to view tooltip data.

I've added a very quick animated gif demonstrating this, would appreciate any help that can be given.

[image: Example of issue]

```
var overview2017 = {jan:[236,40], feb:[301,75]};
// default view for charts
overview(overview2017.jan);
function buttonclass(v){
    var arr = [bJan,bFeb,bMar,bApr,bMay,bJun,bJul,bAug,bSep,bOct,bNov,bDec];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
        arr[i].classList.remove("selected");
    }
    arr[v].classList.add("selected");
}

bJan.addEventListener("click", function(){
    buttonclass(0);
    overview(overview2017.jan);
    clientactivity(clientactivities.janLbls,clientactivities.janData);
    // oprft(chartdata);
});

bFeb.addEventListener("click", function(){
    buttonclass(1);
    overview(overview2017.feb);
    clientactivity(clientactivities.febLbls,clientactivities.febData);
});
```

Chart script

```
function overview(rftdata) {

    var data = {
        labels: ["Activities"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "RFT Acvtivities",
            backgroundColor: WLTYellow,
            data: [rftdata[0]]
            },{
            label: "Non RFT",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)",
            data: [rftdata[1]]
        }]
    };

    var option = {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Total monthly activities"
        },
        responsive: false,
        tooltips: {
            mode: "index",
            intersect: false,
            callbacks: {
                beforeBody: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                    return "RFT %: ";
                },
                // Use the footer callback to display the sum of the items showing in the tooltip
                footer: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                    var sum = 0;
                    tooltipItems.forEach(function(tooltipItem) {
                        sum += data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                    });
                return "Total Activities: " + sum;
                },
            },
            footerFontStyle: "normal"
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                gridLines: {
                    display: true,
                    color: WLTLightGrey
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                gridLines: {
                    display: false
                }
            }]
        }
    };

    Chart.Bar("chart_0", {
        options: option,
        data: data
    });
};
```

Comment: Without knowing more about your subfunctions, I'm guessing it's got something to do with you not destroying \ redrawing the canvas when you try and redo the graph and how chartjs handles being overwritten without clearing its container

Comment: Can you create a working code snippet of your above code using plunker/jsfiddle/codepen etc? It would be easy to look into your issue

Comment: Nout tried this before so hopefully you can access.https://ide.c9.io/puggle/charts#openfile-README.md